# Dynamically change Bootstrap 3.0 badge text using Javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple javascript code that changes the innerText of a badge which is a span. This is works fine in IE but not in firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/5z1426w2/

All I'm doing is setting innerText

```
document.getElementById('myBadge').innerText = "TESTING"
```

Any ideas on getting this to work on firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myBadge').innerHTML = "TESTING"
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` is not actually standard (http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)

Firefox is basically the only major browser that doesn't support it.

In your example, `innerHTML` seems like it would work instead.

`textContent` can also work.